# Exception handling from my custom filter in google cloud endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Whenever a cloud endpoint throws an exception app engine handles those exceptions and sends standard response as follows.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "message" : "java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero",
    "code" : 503,
    "errors" : [ {
      "domain" : "global",
      "reason" : "backendError",
      "message" : "java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero"
    } ]
  }
}
```

But I want to handle those exception in my custom filters and set relevant status code to response.

Also sometimes I want to redirect to different url. How could I do that with endpoints?

Answer (score -1):

What you should do is set up an error handler as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Error_Handlers). That way you can catch all of the [standard exceptions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/exceptions) thrown by endpoints or whatever custom exceptions you throw yourself.

Comment: If I mapped error-page location to JSP, will I have handle of raised exception. Also how to address redirection?

Comment: That example points to a JSP but you can easily redirect that to a URL served by a Servlet/filter and handle everything including redirection in there.